# HTML5 Audio element sends 2 times http get request

Tags: javascript, apache, http, audio, html5-audio

I have access a audio element with 135KB audio data in a HTML file.(using apache server)

**Html code**

```
 <audio id="ring" src="Ring.wav" loop></audio>
```

When I access the HTML page, 1 Http Get request with status 206 fired.(Request range: bytes=0-)

My problem is when I tried to play that audio from Js file ,at the time again Get request with status 206 fired.(Request range: bytes=16044-)

**js code**

```
 var ring = document.getElementById("ring");
 ring.play();
```

Please answer my following questions:

1. Why second time Get request fired.
2. How to change  this multiple Get request to single Get request.

NOTE: I am using firefox 44.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

from the [doc](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), I understand that `206` is for partial content load, my guess is initially when you load the page, it would just check if the source file exists, hence the first call. But when you play it the first time, the actual file is loaded, hence the second `206` call. If you want the whole file to load on page load, you could add attribute [`preload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio), html tag would be something like:

```
<audio id="ring" src="Ring.wav" loop preload></audio>
```

But I am not sure if it is advisable( unless this audio file needed for all use cases), because whenever someone loads the page, the file would be downloaded, which increases the server load unnecessarily.